# is it possible to user `where` and `count` to return the count for a specified field?

Tags: mysql, database, prisma

I am trying to use Prisma to return a count for a boolean field where it equals 'true'.

To give some context, on the frontend I am trying to calculate the workouts that have been completed by a user as a percentage, so ideally I would like prisma to return a count for the total workouts (which I have successfully done) and the count for the userWorkouts where 'isCompleted' equal true (which I am unable to achieve), currently the count is returning all userWorkouts not just the completed ones.

Here is my current Prisma Query:

```
const response = await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    id: 1,
  },
  select: {
    id: true,
    programs: {
      select: {
        program: {
          select: {
            name: true,
            blocks: {
              select: {
                id: true,
                name: true,
                week: {
                  select: {
                    id: true,
                    number: true,
                    workouts: {
                      select: {
                        userWorkouts: {
                          where: {
                            isCompleted: true,
                          },
                        },
                        _count: {
                          select: {
                            userWorkouts: true,
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    },
                    _count: {
                      select: {
                        workouts: true,
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
res.json(response);
};
```

Is this possible to achieve using Primsa? Or should I just return all userWorkouts and filter for isCompleted: true on the frontend?

Comment: Why don't you just make relation between user and userWorkouts? You are doing something very weird and you probably need to read something about data base modeling, at least basics. You can start here for example https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/. If you want some help please post your schema (related parts), we can't really help if we don't know how is your DB looks like

Comment: @Danila how will making a relation between the user and the userWorkouts solve the question I have asked and achieve getting the count for a specific field like I have asked???

Comment: To count something like that you need to use `prisma.*.count` in the first place, not `findUnique` on the completely different table. And that relation would help you to do that. Anyway, without knowing your schema it's almost impossible to help.

Comment: @Danila as per the docs you can count relations prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/…, hence why the part where I return all user workouts works as expected, as I said in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spoken with the Prisma team and this can't be achieved yet, although there is a feature request open for it.

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8413

If you would like to help get this feature added please add you +1 to the feature request.